# Jumping to a specific page within a SharePoint List

Tags: list, performance, paging, query

I was wondering what people think the best way is to jump to a specific page within a sharepoint list, taking into account performance considerations.

eg:

1) List with 1000 items in it

2) Each page contains 10 items

3) Show up to 10 pages at a time.

4) User can jump to any page by typing in the page number (i.e. No Next / Previous)

Here is my thinking

1) Using itemsPerPage = 10, pageNumber = ?

Use 2 Queries and a loop to find the ListItemCollectionPosition and Combine with RowLimit.

i.e.

a) Get the start position

```
ListItemCollectionPosition positionToStart = null;

for (int i = itemsPerPage ; i < itemsPerPage * pageNumber; i + itemsPerPage)
{ 
   SPQuery.RowLimit = itemsPerPage  ;
   var spItems = SPList.GetItems(SPQuery).Items;
   if (spItems.ListItemCollectionPosition != null)
   { 
       positionToStart = spItems.ListItemCollectionPosition;
   }
}
```

b) Get The Results

```
SPQuery.RowLimit = itemsPerPage;
SPQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = positionToStart 
return SPList.GetItems(SPQuery).Items;
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the built in pagination on the list? Is this a custom page that needs something different?

Comment: Yes, this is a custom page that requires <Previous> 1, 2, 3 ,4 <Next>

Comment: How are you displaying the list items? Are you using a gridview or something? A regular list view can be paged so I am just trying to figure out what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Another way that should be considered is the "javascript way" :)

ListData.svc supports easily pagination by adding a "top" and "skip" parameter. I found more info [here](http://mysharepointwork.blogspot.be/2010/09/using-rest-to-get-data-form-sharepoint.html)

You could combine the ajax call with [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) or [XSLT transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa139949%28v=office.10%29.aspx) to obtain the desired UI.

Cheers!

Comment: I have had a lot of success with this method. I've had Kendo UI grid controls getting data from 4 lists to build a mashup with over 3000 items in the grid (client paging) all from a dev server with 2GB RAM and a dual core processor and it took 3 seconds to get all the data. The UI responded quickly and it took about an hour to set up.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only way you can do it is to retrieve (page number * 10) items and then only show the last 10. The ListItemCollectionPosition mechanism is completely built on the next / previous metaphor and will not work otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by this way

```
string lastItemId = null;
int ItemsPerPage = 30; //define how many items will display on one page
int PageNumber = 3; //define page number to show result only from this page

            SPWeb curWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
            SPListCollection lists = curWeb.Lists;
            SPList list = lists.TryGetList(ListName);

                //sorting by custom date column if needed
                string sortField = SortFieldName;
                string newDateField = SortFieldName;
                string displayDate = sortField;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortField))
                {
                    sortField = "ID"; 
                    newDateField = "Created";
                    displayDate = "Created";
                }

                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                if (ItemsPerPage != 0)
                    query.RowLimit = (uint)ItemsPerPage;
                query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='" + sortField + "' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>";

                SPListItemCollection items = null;

                for (int i = 0; i < pageNumber; ++i)
                {
                    items = list.GetItems(query);
                    lastItemId = items.ListItemCollectionPosition.PagingInfo;

                    SPListItemCollectionPosition pos = new SPListItemCollectionPosition(lastItemId);
                    query.ListItemCollectionPosition = pos;

                }
                foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                {
                   //items collection has items from specific page
                }
```

Also you can render page numbers on bottom of custom aspx page.